# Drawing concentric circles in Swift with different Colors using a ForEach loop

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I am using the `SwiftUI` and I want to use a `ForEach` loop that draws concentric circles that adjusts which circle is highlighted with a `Slider`. When I run the following code I get a one circle colored red when I should get the second circle to be blue because the `Stepper` is 2.0. How can I update the color of a view based on the value of a slider. I did not bother adding the slider yet because I wanted to get a constant value working first. Does anyone know how to get these concentric circles stacked on top of each other with one of them showing a different color than the rest depending on the value of a variable?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CircleView: View {
    @State var color = Color.red
    @State var stepperSelector = 2.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach((0...5), id: \.self) { x in
                Path { path in
                    var center = (x: 187, y:240)
                    var radius = Double(185) - Double(x) * Double(185 / 7)
                    let factor = Double(Int(radius)) / 5
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + Int(radius), y: center.y))
                        for i in stride(from: 0, to: 361, by: 1){

                            let center = CGPoint(x: 187, y: 240)
                            let i = Double(i)
                            let radians = i * Double.pi / 180
                            let x = radius * cos(radians) + Double(center.x)
                            let y = radius * sin(radians) + Double(center.y)
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                        }
                }
                .fill(self.color)
                .onAppear{
                    if Int(self.stepperSelector) == Int(x) {
                        self.color = Color.blue
                    } else {
                        self.color = Color.red
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.fill` will fill the inside of the path which is why the single red color circle output. Also, you can switch the color inline without using a separate state var.

```
struct CircleView: View {

    @State var stepperSelector = 2.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach((0...5), id: \.self) { x in
                Path { path in
                    let center = (x: 187, y: 240)
                    let radius = Double(185) - Double(x) * Double(185 / 7)

                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + Int(radius), y: center.y))

                    for i in stride(from: 0, to: 361, by: 1){

                        let center = CGPoint(x: 187, y: 240)
                        let i = Double(i)
                        let radians = i * Double.pi / 180

                        let x = radius * cos(radians) + Double(center.x)
                        let y = radius * sin(radians) + Double(center.y)

                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

                    }
                }
                .stroke(Int(self.stepperSelector) == Int(x) ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Happy to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have another question if you have the time to look, you seem pretty comfortable with SwiftUI as I am new to it

Comment: here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61472189/swift-ui-rotation-inside-foreach-loop