# Swift UI rotation inside ForEach loop

Tags: swift, foreach, swift3, rotation, swiftui

Excuse the length of this question, but I have a swift UI that has words displayed in concentric circles. I want to be able to press the right and left button and have the words rotate clockwise and counterclockwise respectively. My `withAnimation{}` button function works as long as the text is not in a ForEach loop. Is there a way to change state variables that are in a ForEach loop? In my case animate a rotation of a view that is within a ForEach. In this case I want to use the slider to pick which level I am rotating.

code:
    import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var circle = Circle()

    @State var platform: Float = 0.0

    @State var platformBool = false

    @State var colors = [Color.red, Color.black, Color.orange, Color.white, Color.green, Color.gray, Color.blue]
    @State var colorOne = Color.red

    @State var colorTwo = Color.black

    @State var levelWords = [["A","B","O","R","T","S"], ["B","E","N","I","G","N"], ["A","B","O","R","T","S"], ["B","E","N","I","G","N"], ["A","B","O","R","T","S"], ["B","E","N","I","G","N"]]

    @State var angle = Double(0)

    @State var angles = [Double(0), Double(0), Double(0), Double(0), Double(0), Double(0),]

    @State var radius: CGFloat = 175.0

    var body: some View {

        let rows = (self.levelWords[0].count)
        let columns = (self.levelWords.count)

        let radiiStep: CGFloat = self.radius / CGFloat(self.levelWords[0].count + 1)
        let degreeStep = Double(360 / self.levelWords[0].count)

        func floatValue(one: CGFloat, two: CGFloat, three: Int) -> CGFloat {

            let float = CGFloat(three)
            let floatValue = one - two * float

            return -floatValue

        }

        func degreeValue(one: Double, two: Double, three: Double) -> Double {

            let value = -(one + two * three)

            return value
        }

        return
            VStack {

                ZStack{

                    self.circle
                        .fill(RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black, Color.blue]), center: .center, startRadius: 30, endRadius: 200))

                    ForEach(0..<columns) { column in
                         ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                            Text("\(self.levelWords[column][row])")
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(degreeValue(one: self.angles[column], two: Double(row), three: degreeStep)))
                                .offset(y: floatValue(one: self.radius, two: radiiStep, three: column))
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.angles[column] + Double(row) * degreeStep))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                    }

                    Text("rot")
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.angles[Int(self.platform)]))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                }

                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Left") {
                        withAnimation{
                            self.angles[Int(self.platform)] -= Double(360 / self.levelWords[0].count)
                            print(self.angles[Int(self.platform)])
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    Button("Right") {
                         withAnimation{
                            self.angle += Double(360 / self.levelWords[0].count)
                            print("rotated")
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }


                Slider(value: $platform, in: 0...5)
                    .padding()

                Text("platform: \(Int(platform))")
                .padding()

            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating one text label per word in your levelWords 2d array and you want to be able to choose which of those labels you rotate, is that correct?  Couldn't you create a state var that is a 2d array of Text objects so you can rotate them later?

Comment: This looks similar to one I solved here [Problem animating with animatableData in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138206/12299030)